# Merge list of lists and return in a loop

Tags: list, merge, lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to merge all list of lists into one.

Here is my code so far:

```
(DEFUN DESCRIPTION (BLOCK)
    (loop initially (setf result '())
        for desc in (DESC2 BLOCK) 
        do (append result desc)
        finally (return result)
        )
)
```

The function (DESC2 BLOCK) returns the following:

```
((SHAPE BRICK) (COLOR GREEN) (SIZE SMALL) (SUPPORTED-BY B2) (SUPPORTED-BY B3))
```

I simply need the function to return a merged list:

```
(SHAPE BRICK COLOR GREEN SIZE SMALL SUPPORTED-BY B2 SUPPORTED-BY B3)
```

I have tried so many ways and have researched so much. I am sorry, but I don't fully know the LISP language, and would appreciate it if you can help me!

Thank You in advance!

Comment: Bad style. Instead of `initially (setf random-dynamic-variable init-value)` you might want to use `with local-variable = init-value`.  `with` variables are bound once and in scope of the loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just append the sublists in a `LOOP`:

```
CL-USER 23 > (loop for l in '((SHAPE BRICK) (COLOR GREEN) (SIZE SMALL)
                              (SUPPORTED-BY B2) (SUPPORTED-BY B3))
                   append l)
(SHAPE BRICK COLOR GREEN SIZE SMALL SUPPORTED-BY B2 SUPPORTED-BY B3)
```

or use `REDUCE` to `APPEND`

```
CL-USER 24 > (reduce #'append
                     '((SHAPE BRICK) (COLOR GREEN) (SIZE SMALL)
                       (SUPPORTED-BY B2) (SUPPORTED-BY B3)))
(SHAPE BRICK COLOR GREEN SIZE SMALL SUPPORTED-BY B2 SUPPORTED-BY B3)
```

or use `MAPCAN`

```
CL-USER 25 > (mapcan #'copy-list
                     '((SHAPE BRICK) (COLOR GREEN) (SIZE SMALL)
                       (SUPPORTED-BY B2) (SUPPORTED-BY B3)))
(SHAPE BRICK COLOR GREEN SIZE SMALL SUPPORTED-BY B2 SUPPORTED-BY B3)
```

`MAPCAN` *maps* a function over a list and concatenates the result lists destructively. Thus use `COPY-LIST` to copy the sub lists.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew that I was making it harder then it really was!